# Regular expression for phone number with some exlussion

Tags: regex

We have come across on validation for which we have following rules,

First character should always be "0" or "+46" or "0046"

Should be of length between 8 - 20 (including + if have)

And block following number,

(0900x, +46900x, 0046900x).

(0939x, +46939x, 0046939x).

(0944x, +46944x, 0046944x).

(099x, +4699x, 00469x).

Can you help me to create regular expression, I tried creating and testing it on https://regex101.com/ but it pretty hard for me to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way would be

```
^(?:0|\+46|0046)(?:900|939|944|99)
```

It starts by checking for country code or preceding `0` and then the 4 combinations of area code.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qC6gK2/2).

**Edit**

If you want numbers **not** matching your rules, you can try the same with a negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!(?:0|\+46|0046)(?:900|939|944|99)).*
```

[See this one here](https://regex101.com/r/qC6gK2/3).

or without negative look-ahead:

```
^(?:[^0+]|0[^09]|\+[^4]|\+4[^6]|(?:\+46[^9])|(?:0046[^9])).*$
```

[and this one here](https://regex101.com/r/qC6gK2/4).

**Edit 2**

OK, here we go again ;)

This turned out to be a tough one. But here we go:

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(?>\+46|0046|0(?!0))(?!900|939|944|99)\+?\d*
```

- Add a positive look-ahead in the beginning to assert the length is correct
- use a atomic group to match the country code - **not** allowing another double zero `00`
- Negativ look-ahead to disallow toll numbers.

Also changed so it only allows digits (and the optional `+` in the beginning).

[See **this** one here](https://regex101.com/r/qC6gK2/6).

Comment: actually need single expression to allow content start with "0" or "+46" or "0046" and block having 900, 939, 944, 99 after that. so expression should not match in case of 00469001234, 00469391234, 00469441234, 0046991234 and similar in case of number start with 0 or +46.

Comment: So you want to test for negatives? If your regex flavor supports negative look-aheads, try `^(?!(?:0|\+46|0046)(?:900|939|944|99)).*`. [See it here](https://regex101.com/r/qC6gK2/3).

Comment: that looks working in some scenario, we need that length should be 8 -20 chars, and start with 0 or +46 or 0046, I tried to do this using ^(?!(?:0|\+46|0046)(?:900|939|944|99))[+|\d]{8,20}, but that passed 123456789, can you tell where I am wrong here?